# Is there any relation between the modular inverse of the same integer under different modulus?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I mean, suppose
$$ab \equiv 1 \mod{m}$$
$$ac \equiv 1 \mod{n}$$
I wonder if there is any relation between $b$ and $c$?
Could we compute one from another?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no relation if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime. Of course if $d = (m,n) > 1$ then one necessary relation is that $b \equiv c \bmod d$. (That's also true if $d = 1$, but then it would not say anything serious.)

Comment: **Hint:**

Try small numbers.

Comment: Look for the Chinese Remainder Theorem, it covers just this case. It says essentially that if $\gcd(m, n) = 1$, $a$ can be anything in $1 \le a \le m n$.